# Is there a way to add an empty element to an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've seen posts where you use a variation of .push() .push(undefined) and .push(null) but none seem to work.. my issue might be that when I am joining the list into a string, it gets rid of the empty ones.

The ultimate goal is to iterate through an array of arrays, then for each item in a "row", remove commas from the item if it is a string, and has a comma. My code is messy, I apologize.

Due to a lot of comments I shortened the code as much as I could.. I wanted to include my .join() because I think that might be part of my issue, thanks.

```
    let someRow = [6, "Gaston,OH", "Brumm", "Male", , , , 2554];
    function remCommas(row) {
      let newRow = [];
      for (let item in row) {
        if (typeof row[item] === "string") {
          let Str = row[item].split();
          console.log(Str);
          let newStr = [];
          for (let char in Str) {
            if (Str[char] !== ",") {
              newStr.push(Str[char]);
            }
          }
          newRow.push(newStr.join());
        } else {
          newRow.push(row[item]);
        }
      }
      console.log(newRow);
      return newRow;
    }
    remCommas(someRow);

//          input: [6, "Gaston, OH", "Brumm", "Male", , , , 2554]
//expected output: [6, "Gaston OH", "Brumm", "Male", , , , 2554]
//  current ouput: [6, "Gaston, OH", "Brumm", "Male", 2554]
```

Comment: what is an "empty element" for you? There is a difference between having `undefined` as an element, and actually having a sparse array, even if it's very subtle.

Comment: in my console.log in my browser, it shows the following: 
[6, "Gaston", "Brumm", "Male", empty × 3, 2554]

and if you  click the arrow, it shows the index skip from 3 to 7.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], with example inputs and outputs, especially with what you're expecting to get, and what you're actually getting. Note that [using `for..in` over an array is considered a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/215552).

Comment: it's good to put code, but it should be simplified so that it only reflects the question asked, not the equation of a trip to mars

Comment: @MisterJojo I appologize.. I tried to simplify it more than before, I hope it is bearable to read now (:

Comment: It isn't clear your goal. for instance for the input [6, "Gaston", "Brumm", "Male", , , , 2554]; what is the expected output.

Comment: @Umbert Sorry for not making my question clear, first time posting. I cleaned it up a bit with input/output examples at the bottom.

Comment: help me to understand, the goal is remove the `,` from each string element in the row?

Comment: I would recommend using `replace`. Str.replace(',' , ' ') does what I think you're trying to accomplish. For instance `"Gaston, OH".replace(',', ' ')` === `"Gaston OH"`. That would simplify your code further.

Comment: @Angrysheep I actually just found this while looking around, and I am trying to implement it now!

Comment: @QuethzelDíaz My main issue is my array gets shortened after I use .join(). It will not keep the "empty" elements or placeholders in my array. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @Brandons404 Good luck. Let us know if you're still having trouble!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hardest part was to understand the question, well if I understood correctly?

```js
const input_Row = [6, "Gaston, OH", "Brumm", "Male", , , , 2554];

let output_Row = input_Row.map(row=>(typeof row==='string') ?row.replace(/,/g,'') :row)

console.log ('input_Row', input_Row)
console.log ('output_Row', output_Row)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, this works! I deeply apologize for the confusion and will aim to be as clear as possible in the future. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Please note this code version leaves the holes in the array thus you will have [6, "Gaston OH", "Brumm", "Male", undefined,undefined ,undefined , 2554]; because the map ignores the holes.

Comment: @Umbert Yes, I understand, this was my goal. To remove commas and to keep those undefined's in there, as I will be exporting the data to a spreadsheet and need to keep the cell data in the correct columns. Thank you for the follow up, though. (: